# Is the jQuery intellisense plugin available for Visual Studio now?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

Is the jQuery intellisense plugin available for Visual Studio now?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. [Rich Intellisense for JQuery](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/10/28/rich-intellisense-for-jquery.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [This blog](http://mwtech.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-get-jquery-intellisense-working.html) taught me how to do it.